# How can I fix CodeIgniter from tinkering with my internal links to pictures?

Tags: php, codeigniter, hyperlink

I am using the CodeIgniter framework to work on my latest website. In my views, I am trying to load graphics from another folder, external of the CodeIgniter installation.

However, CodeIgniter is rewriting the links when I use absolute links to the resources.

Is there a way I can configure it to allow absolute links, rather than re-writing them?

Comment: what is it rewriting them to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you probably need to use the URL helper function base_url()

**Like so:**

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url()?>directory/images/graphic.png" />
```

This example assumes the directory is in the root of your public_html, **and that $config['base_url'] is set correctly in application/config/config.php.**

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://dev.testing.com/site/";
```

You also need to load the URL Helper in your controlling class.

**Like so**

```
 class MyClass extends Controller{

 function MyClass()
 { 
  parent::Controller();
  $this->load->helper('url');
 }

 }
```

If your still having problems, go back into application/config/config.php and try changing:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO";
```

To:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI";
```

Comment: That looks like the more 'CI' way to do links anyways. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What code are you using to output the links?

Codeigniter shouldn't be messing with absolute links, infact it will only mess with it if you pass it through site_url() or similar.

Comment: I'm just writing the links directly inside of a view.

Comment: As in <img src="http://www.domain.tld/graphics/image.png" /> or <a href="http://www.domain.tld/graphics/image.png">link</a> ? As long as it doesn't go through a CI function CI won't touch it. Basic question, but always worth asking, you're not missing the http:// are you? Could it be a .htaccess issue?